# How to assert a value within an array which is not always returned in response

Tags: karate

abit of a tricky one and i'll attempt to explain it as clearly as possible.

**Schema:**

```
    "dogs": {
        "dogId": "string",
        "breed": [
            {
                "canaan": true,
                "akita": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
    "dogs": {
        "dogId": "70872490",
        "breed": []
    }
}
```

**Feature File:**

```
[...] 

    And match each response.dogs contains
"""
    {
        "dogId": "##regex ^[0-9A-Za-z]*$",
        "breed": [
            {
                "canaan": "##boolean",
                "akita": "##boolean"
            }
        ]
    }
"""
```

**Error:**

`path: $[0].breed[*], actual: [], expected: {canaan=##string, akita=##string}, reason: actual value does not contain expected`

As you can see from the above, the `breed` array sometimes doesn't return any values and at times and at other times, the array may be populated with `canaan` or `akita` values. What is the most elegant way to assert this kind of behaviour? I have tried optional assertions but it seems to always expect the array value to be present.

Let me know your thoughts, any support is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Code:

```
Feature: Validation

    Scenario:
        * def isValid = function(x){ return x == "[]" || karate.match(x,karate.valuesOf([{"canaan":"#boolean","akita":"#boolean"}])).pass }    
        * def schema =
            """
            {
                "dogs": {
                        "dogId": "##regex ^[0-9A-Za-z]*$",
                        "breed": '#? isValid(_)'
                }
            }
            """         
        * def resp1 =
        """
            {
                "dogs": {
                    "dogId": "70872490",
                    "breed": []
                }
            }
        """
        * def resp2 =
        """
            {
                "dogs": {
                    "dogId": "70872490",
                    "breed": [
                            {
                                "canaan": true,
                                "akita": false
                            }
                        ]
                }
            }
        """
        * match resp1 == schema
        * match resp2 == schema
```

Comment: Superb! Works like a treat. Thanks.